# Making turtles appear randomly on specific patches

Tags: gis, netlogo

Using GIS, I created a road map of a city. I want turtles to appear randomly on any of the patches with the road during the setup. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the "n-of", "with" and "sprout" commands will get the job done.

```
to world                                           ## This block will make the colors, 
                                                   ##you won't want to use this but it made the example reproducible
 ask patches [set pcolor random 50]
end

to make_turtles
  let Q 5                                          ##set this to the number of patches you want to spawn a turtle
  ask n-of Q patches with [pcolor = 30] [sprout 1] ##tells Q number of random of patches with 
                                                   ##the desired character (in this case pcolor = 30)
                                                   ## to sprout 1 turtle
end
```

you can change the with [XXX] bit to be

```
with [ROAD=TRUE]
```

if you'd like to put a reproducible example of with the owned variables it'd be easier to give you a more useful answer

Answer (score 0):

patches [roads?]

turtles-own [home-patch]

to setup

setup-drivers

end

to setup-drivers
  create-drivers number-of-cars [
     set home-patch one-of patches with [ roads? = true]
    set shape "airplane"
    set color 25
    set size 8
    move-to home-patch
   ]
end